# Align profile fields using css

Tags: css, alignment

I have a page with the following format,

```
My Profile<br />
Name <span class='values'>: $name</span><br />
 Age <span class='values'>: $age</span><br />
```

etc...

I want to align the fields such that colon is centered followed by the values retrieved from db.

I used a span class with the following info but still the colon is not in the same line.

```
.values {
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
padding-left:100px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to enclose labels (name, age) in an inline-block element with fixed width and align text in them to right. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ULNG5/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap all the labels in one div, then wrap all your values in another div, float those divs side-by-side, then text-align: right on the first div with your labels.